# Rmarkdown password with getPass

Tags: r, passwords, r-markdown, getpass

I am building an application in RMarkdown that relies upon a user-generated password:

```
library(getPass)

pw <- getPass(msg = "Enter the Password, please!")
```

When I run all of the code interactively in the R console, the getPass function pauses the code and provides a popup window in which a user can enter the password.

However, when including this code in RMarkdown, the knitting process does not halt for getPass to do its work.  As a result, the code runs without the password.  In this case, it prevents the application from connecting to the password-protected database.

Do any of you have a recommendation for how to resolve this issue?  I have searched for similar questions, but if this is a duplicate, then my apologies.  Thank you!

Comment: Rmarkdown rendering is not meant to be interactive: graphics/plots are all captured to be rendered (to html, pdf, etc), so the pop-up window is either (a) just another graphic, or (b) something that is not waited-on or even permitted. An option would be to use `params` feature of Rmarkdown documents, and create a function that prompts for the password and passes it with something like `rmarkdown::render("path/to/file.Rmd", params=list(pass=pw))` (allowing for other arguments to `render`).

Comment: Thank you, r2evans!  That worked very well.

Comment: Just curious: when using RStudio, is there a way to get the `rmarkdown::render` to pop up the preview window?

Answer (score 6):

As [stated in comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44853032/rmarkdown-password-with-getpass?rq=1#comment76687949_44853032) use [parameterized report](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/params-knit.html).

Your rmarkdown should look like:

```
---
output: html_document
params:
  pwd:
    label: "Enter the Password, please!"
    value: ""
    input: password
---

Your password is `r params$pwd`
```

Now either run

```
rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd", params="ask")
```

or use RStudio button "Knitr with parameters":

[image: where to klik]